# Oracle Save decimal in a column with number datatype

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table where one of the column has datatype **number(20)**. In one of the cases I need to save a value which is decimal into the column but the column automatically converts it into a whole number. Below is a simple test table I created to test this scenario.

```
create table test_tbl
(
  amt    number(20)
)

insert into test_tbl values (9.999)
```

The above inserts a value of 10 rather than 9.999. How can I save 9.999 exactly as it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle, you may (but are not required to) give both a precision and a scale to columns of `NUMBER` data type. `NUMBER(20)` is valid shorthand for `NUMBER(20,0)`, meaning 20 digits, **none** after the decimal point.

How to fix it depends on your needs. Normally a `NUMBER` column should be declared simply as `NUMBER`. Specify precision and scale only if you have a good reason to.

For example: if your numbers must be limited to no more than 20 digits before the decimal point and no more than six decimal places (after the decimal point), the total PRECISION is 20 + 6 = 26. You would then declare `NUMBER(26, 6)`.

You can change a column declared as `NUMBER(20)` to `NUMBER` (if that meets your needs otherwise), since there is no loss of information in this change. However, note that numbers that are ALREADY saved in the column have ALREADY LOST information, which cannot be recovered from the table; you will need to go to the original source of those numbers, if you need to fix it.

Brief demo (notice in the last output that the row inserted BEFORE the change has its value forever changed to 10, with no recovery possible):

```
create table test_tbl
(
  amt    number(20)
);

insert into test_tbl values (9.999);

select * from test_tbl;

AMT
---
 10

alter table test_tbl modify (amt number);

insert into test_tbl values (9.999);

select * from test_tbl;

  AMT
-----
   10
9.999
```

Comment: That helps me..may be I can suggest the idea of changing number(20) to number without any precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `NUMBER(20,18)`, or `BINARY_FLOAT`,`BINARY_DOUBLE` will be more

> NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]  Number having precision `p` and scale `s`. 
>   Range of p : From 1 to 38. 
>   Ranges of s : From -84 to 127. 
>   Both precision and scale are in decimal digits.

```
create table test_tbl
(
   amt NUMBER(20,18)
);

insert into test_tbl values (9.99948489);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM test_tbl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39e79d/1/0)**:

```
|        AMT |
|------------|
| 9.99948489 |
```

Comment: the table I created is a test table. What if changing data type is not an option?

Comment: @DG3 - If changing data type is not an option, then you can't save non-integers in that column, period. However, you don't really need to change the data **type**, you only need to change the precision and the scale.

Comment: If you can't  change the type of the column you are hosed. Can't store the fractional part of the number. I guess you could multiply it by a large enough power of 10 that you get an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Always create AMOUNT and NUMERIC fields as NUMBER datatype without Scale and Precision unless you are very sure about your field precision. This should solve your issue.